# Convert JSON object to object which not in JSON format

Tags: javascript, json, object

I have a JSON object with the structure as below

```
const inputObj = {
    "prop1": "val1",
    "prop2": {
        "prop2_1": "val2_1",
        "prop2_2": "val2_2"
    }
    "prop3": "val3"
}
```

My objective: I would like to take the property, including the nested property, and store the result in a `txt` file, but not in JSON format. To make it clear, here is my expected output in the `txt` file:

```
{
    prop1: {
        id: 'prop1'
    },
    prop2_prop2_1: {
        id: 'prop2.prop2_1'
    },
    prop2_prop2_2: {
        id: 'prop2.prop2_2'
    }
    prop3: {
        id: 'prop3'
    }
}
```

So far, I could write the non nested property, but still not in the structure which I expected. Here is the result so far:

```
{
    "prop1": "prop1",
    "prop3": "prop3"
}
```

Its still in JSON format, not in the structure that I expected, and the nested property still not caught (I still thinking how to get it)

here is the code so far to make my current result:

```
const fs = require('fs')
const fileName = "./results.txt"

function getAllKeys(obj, path = [], result = []) {
  Object.entries(obj).forEach(([k, v]) => {
    if (typeof v === 'object') getAllKeys(v, path.concat(k), result)
    else result.push(path.concat(k).join("."))
  })
  return result
}

const inputToFile = getAllKeys(inputObj)
// console.log(inputToFile)
// result of the console.log
// prop1
// prop2.prop2_1
// prop2.prop2_2
// prop3

const newObj = {}

for (var i = 0; i < inputToFile.length; i++) {
    var input = inputToFile[i]
    var dotIndex = input.indexOf('.') // to check if its from the nested JSON property of the inputObj
    if (dotIndex === -1) {
        // no dot or nested property in the JSON
        newObj[input] = input.toString()
    } else {
        // if the input contain dot, which is a nested JSON
    }
}

fs.writeFileSync(fileName, JSON.stringfy(newObj))
// if I use above line, the result in the file is as I had mention above. But, if the code is like below:
const finals = JSON.stringfy(newObj)
fs.writeFileSync(fileName, JSON.parse(finals))
// the output in the file is only "[Object object]" without double quote
```

**Update**
The reason why I need the result to be formatted like that, is because I want to use react-intl. I already have the locale file (the translation), which looks like the inputObj (the structure). Then, I need to make a file, which like this (below), so the lib could translate it:

```
import { defineMessages } from 'react-intl';

const MessagesId = defineMessages({
  prop1: {
    id: 'prop1'
  },
  prop2_prop2_1: {
    id: 'prop2.prop2_1'
  },
  prop2_prop2_2: {
    id: 'prop2.prop2_2'
  },
  prop3: {
    id: 'prop3'
  }
})
export default MessagesId;
```

Thats why, I need it to be not like JSON. Because I already have thousand codes for the translation, but need to define it in the MessagesId. It would be so much takes time rite if I do it manually .__.
Ps: the react-intl is works, the problem is only the converting as my initial questions

Comment: While this is *possible*, it's really sounds like an X/Y problem - JSON format is by far the most common way of serializing / deserializing nested objects/arrays.

Comment: @CertainPerformance actually, the reasons why I dont want the result in JSON format is because I want to create it then use it not for data transfer, but for something else that require to be formatted like that because the library could read in the expected output structure. I already have thousand line of codes in the JSON format like in the inputObj variable. But now, I need it to be as the expected structure above.

Comment: Better to fix the library so that it can read the de-facto standard than to try to tweak your code to something non-standard

Comment: @CertainPerformance anw, I am using react-intl for translation. I'll update my questions. Maybe u have better approach. Please let me know

Comment: @CertainPerformance thank you, for your response. I was wrong. I thought it has to be not in JSON format. But, when I try to change into JSON format, the translation stil working. Thank you for ur response. Sorry for my mistakes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This script can handle multiple levels of nestied object.

```
const outputObj = {};
const convertNestedObj = (obj, parentKey = []) => {
  for (key in obj) {
    newParentKey = [...parentKey, key];
    if (typeof obj[key] === 'object') {
      convertNestedObj(obj[key], newParentKey);
    } else {
      outputObj[newParentKey.join('_')] = { id: newParentKey.join('_') };
    }
  }
};
convertNestedObj(inputObj);
```